# Двоеточие или запятая (2)

Tags: синтаксис

В предложениях:
1) За рулём сидел Игорь (запятая или двоеточие) он ехал медленно, чтобы машину не занесло.
2) С помощью магии я определяю (запятая или двоеточие) всё ли в порядке или нет.
Какой знак препинания уместен?

Answer (score 1):

Начнём по порядку:

1. **За рулём сидел Игорь, он ехал медленно, чтобы машину не занесло.**

В данном случае следует поставить запятую, служащую для бессоюзной связи между предложениями, где сказуемые, являвшиеся бы однородным при обычном перечислении, относятся к одному лицу, Игорю.

2. **С помощью магии я определяю, всё ли в порядке или нет.**

Второе предложение является отчасти сокращенным (пропущен, скажем, союз "что"), содержащим главную и придаточную части (придаточную часть сложно обнаружить из-за отсутствия союза и вопросительной интонации предложения). Если возникают затруднения, старайтесь перестроить предложение.

**UPD**: товарищи знатоки, прав ли я насчёт второго случая?

Comment: *>> Второе предложение является отчасти сокращенным (пропущен, скажем, союз "что")... товарищи знатоки, прав ли я насчёт второго случая?*. Неправы, причем грубо неправы. Интересно, откуда вы такое берете?

Comment: Просто рассуждаю, поэтому и пишу, что не уверен в правильности ответа. К сожалению, в моём учебники такие тонкости не описывались.