# Двоеточие перед "всё" или запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика

В предложении

*С помощью магии я определяю (: или ,) всё ли в порядке или нет*

какой нужен знак препинания?

Comment: Стилистически здесь лучше убрать "или нет", либо "ли".

Comment: Я уже отвечал на подобный вопрос [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/452199/Двоеточие-или-запятая-2)

Comment: @БотБотович: слушай, как ты гиперссылку в комментарии сделал?

Comment: Только сегодня обнаружил, что такое возможно. Отправил ответ с ней, который засчитали за комментарий.

Answer (score 1):

***С помощью магии я определяю, всё ли в порядке или нет.***

1) Это сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП) с изъяснительной придаточной  частью, но вместо обычного **подчинительного союза** используется **вопросительная частица ЛИ**.

2) Соответственно, в этом предложении ставится запятая, а не двоеточие, как в бессоюзном сложном предложении (БСП), например:
***С помощью магии я определил: здесь всё в порядке.***

3) Двоеточие может использоваться в СПП, но в этом случае оно является **неосновным знаком,** требующим определенных условий http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=143#pp143

Например:

*С помощью магии я определяю **следующее**: всё ли в порядке или нет, насколько серьезны проблемы, можно ли  что-либо исправить и как это сделать.*